# What ways currently exist to cast a spell that normally requires an action as a Bonus Action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions

Using all official 5th edition sources except Unearthed Arcana, what are the ways that I can cast a spell from my character's spell list that normally requires an Action, as a Bonus Action?

Comment: Usual remark, you cannot cast two spells on the same turn unless one of them is a 1 action cantrip (PHB 202)

Comment: Yes, the intent is to expend an Action that isn't to cast a spell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are currently 2 class features that allow you to cast an action spell with a bonus action: The Sorcerer's Quickened Spell metamagic, and the Oath of the Ancients Paladin's Elder Champion feature.

There is 1 magic item that does the same thing: The Tome of the Stilled Tongue.

Comment: Xanathar's might have added a few more such options, such as the grave cleric's ability to cast Spare the Dying as a bonus action. (There might be some in SCAG as well; I'm not sure.)